# Exceptions coming everytime I open and close my app

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, exception

Each time I open my application or closing it or turning off my internet this exception is coming
this was started coming after I have implemented the retrofit in my gradle but now after removing retrofit this exception persists also all the threads in my project are surrounded by try catch, what's this exception?

```
2020-06-26 10:41:08.924 2002-2437/? E/aocb: Phenotype API error. Event # cbxl@9dccd77, EventCode: 12 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    aobf: 29503
        at aoch.b(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):27)
        at aocb.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):91)
        at aocb.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):86)
        at zzu.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):10)
        at bmsn.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):2)
        at snn.b(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):12)
        at snn.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at stk.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-06-26 10:41:08.925 2002-2437/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetCommittedConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 29503, resolution=null}]
        at aocb.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):93)
        at aocb.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):86)
        at zzu.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):10)
        at bmsn.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):2)
        at snn.b(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):12)
        at snn.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at stk.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-06-26 10:41:08.926 2002-2491/? E/NetRec: [99] alee.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: rjr: 29503: 
        at auzd.b(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):5)
        at auzd.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):23)
        at alee.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):1)
        at alee.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):4)
        at aled.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):18)
        at sii.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):1)
        at brl.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):9)
        at sij.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):14)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):7)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):1)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):2)
     Caused by: rjr: 29503: 
        at rpf.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):4)
        at aobp.b(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):3)
        at aoch.a(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):8)
        at zzu.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):18)
        at bmsn.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):2)
        at snn.b(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):12)
        at snn.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at stk.run(:com.google.android.gms@202117022@20.21.17 (040700-316502805):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: You are probably worrying over nothing. These exceptions originate from some other apps. @Amit Ghosh, is there anything else abnormal ? If your app crashes or something else, then you are looking at the logs. There will be something else useful in the logs. If there is no issue, you are probably good to go. Also,you can limit the logcat's visible logs to your current application only.

Comment: No my app is not crashing and thankyou very much your comment has provided me an immense relief by the way.

Answer (score 1):

try Adding this

```
try{ 
     //your code 
}
catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: like a said I have surrounded all my runnable with try catch